# Auto update not working in elasticsearch with Mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am having problem with Elasticsearch-jdbc river data automatically updates if anything updated in Mysql. Here is my Elastic Code

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
    "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Dbname",
    "user" : "user",
    "password" : "password",
      "sql": "select id, firstname, lastname from mytable",                  
      "poll" : "6s",
      "strategy": "simple",
      "scale": 0,
      "autocommit": true,
      "bulk_size": 5000,
      "max_bulk_requests": 30,
      "bulk_flush_interval": "5s",
      "fetchsize": 100,
      "max_rows": 149669,
      "max_retries": 3,
      "max_retries_wait": "10s",
      "locale": "in",
      "digesting": true
    }
}
```

When i insert a new row or updates any data, it is not getting reflected in  elastic. It always show the first time indexed data. Is there anything missing from my end. Please Advise.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything useful in the logs?

Comment: @Val No Nothing happened in log.  For your information My ES Version is 1.4.2 and JDBC is elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.4.0.10.